# Parse log and plot graph using splunk

Tags: splunk

LogLevel="INFO" ServerName="test" HEALTH_CHECK_STATUS="OK"  DATETIME="29-3-2017 13:15:00"
LogLevel="INFO" ServerName="test" EALTH_CHECK_STATUS="OK"  DATETIME="29-3-2017 13:20:00"
LogLevel="INFO" ServerName="test" HEALTH_CHECK_STATUS="OK"  DATETIME="29-3-2017 13:25:00"
LogLevel="INFO" ServerName="test" HEALTH_CHECK_STATUS="OK"  DATETIME="29-3-2017 13:30:00"
LogLevel="INFO" ServerName="test" HEALTH_CHECK_STATUS="FAILED"  DATETIME="29-3-2017 13:35:00"

I am trying to plot the graph for HEALTH_CHECK_STATUS. 
Help required for the same. I tried using timechart. But all requires number as input. Is it possible to convert the "OK" and "FAILED" and plot the graph in splunk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

index=myindex HEALTH_CHECK_STATUS| eval health=if(HEALTH_CHECK_STATUS="OK",100,0) | timechart values(health) as healthstatus